# Remove currently looped item from collection?

Tags: vba, excel

How do I remove the currently looped item from a collection? I get run-time error 13: Type mismatch on the line wls.Remove vl

```
Sub FocusOnH(ByRef vls As Collection)
    Dim vl As CVegetableLine
    For Each vl In vls
        If vl.hValue <> 0 Then
            vl.volume = vl.hValue
        Else
            vls.Remove vl
        End If
    Next vl
End Sub
```

Comment: vl is a user defined object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Collection.Remove()` method takes either `key` (if provided with the `.Add()` method) or `index` (*by default*) as parameter, so you can't provide an user-defined object as parameter to the `Remove()` method which explains the Type-mismatch error.

See a more on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265369%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

---

You should really be using a `Dictionary` collection if you are working with User Defined Types.

---

To achieve what you want use an iterator

```
dim i as long 
for i = Collection.Count to 1 step -1
    'Collection.Remove i
next i
```

Comment: How can I achieve what I am trying to do? Do you see any alternative solution?

Comment: For example, maybe I can work with the index instead of for each?

Comment: Why should I use a dictionary rather than collection if I'm working with user defined type? I read some articles about the two, and couldn't discern a reason.

Comment: @user1283776 this would be a great another question if you can't already find a duplicate on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 7):

You must delete item while looping through the collection in backward order, otherwise it will cause error.

```
Sub TestRemoveItemInCollection()
    Dim col As Collection, i As Integer
    Set col = New Collection
    col.Add "item1"
    col.Add "item2"
    col.Add "item3"
    col.Add "item4"

    ' Never use: For i=1 to col.Count
    For i = col.Count To 1 Step -1
        col.Remove i
    Next i

    Set col = Nothing
End Sub
```

Why? Because Visual Basic collections are re-indexed automatically. If you try to delete in forward order, it will conflict with the outer loop and hence get the tricky error.

Another example, to remove all items in the collection can be done like this:

```
For i = 1 to col.Count
    col.Remove 1 'Always remove the first item.
Next i
```

Comment: It's IMHO an important addition, why it must be looped in reverse order as otherwise the for loop removes all items. Thanks for this hint!