# Remove an object off of Collection - Type Mismatch VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add and remove people from a schedule using collections in Excel with VBA. The steps are:

1. Create 100 people and assign them the first week of schedule
2. Remove them from this first week and calculate the next week
3. Add the person to the next scheduled week.

The remove portion of the second looped providers a Runtime error 13, Type Mismatch error, similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23511563/remove-currently-looped-item-from-collection) question. I have tried the solution in the previous question with the same error. I am unsure how to refer to the `person` index number to remove the proper `person` object.

```
   Sub test()

    Dim person as New Clsperson 'User defined Object
    Dim i as Integer
    Dim j as Integer
    Dim next_list as Integer
    Dim weeks(1 To 52) as New Collection

    'Creating 100 people, assigning them first week, and placing on collection
    For i = 1 To 100
        Set person = New Clsperson
        person.first_time =  WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 5)
        weeks(person.first_time).add person  
    Next i

     For i = 1 To 52
        If weeks(i).Count > 0 Then
            For j = 1 To weeks(i).Count
                Set person= weeks(i).Item(j)

                weeks(i).Remove person 'THIS PROVIDES ERROR

                next_list = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(4, 6)

                person.next_time = person.first_time+ next_list 

                If person.next_time> 52 Then
                    person.next_time = person.next_time - 52
                End If

            weeks(person.next_time).add person

            Next j
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: When removing items from a list, start at the end and work back. Otherwise, you go past the end of the list, because there is one fewer item in the list each time you delete one, but the loop never gets shorter. This is reflected in the answer to the post you linked, which shows a downward loop using `Step -1`.

Comment: When I replace `For j = 1 To weeks(i).Count` to `For j = weeks(i).Count To 1 Step -1`, I'm still getting a Type mismatch error on the `weeks(i). Remove person line`. I've also tried replacing `For i=1 To 52`.

Comment: How were you able to define `.next` as a property?  `Next` is a keyword. Could you post the code of your Class?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - My apologies, that was a typo when I copied the code over.

Comment: Your code still does not run. It seems you never set any of the Collection items.  It is frustrating to try to provide assistance when the code you provide does not execute up to the error point you are concerned about.

Comment: Also, I don't think your Collections are being formed the way you intend. You should inspect them and try to debug that.  Finally, the argument for `Remove` is the `Index` which for a collection object, needs to be a string or the index number. Yours is an object.  Hence, the type-mismatch.

Comment: You can't introduce a typo if you properly *copy/paste* your code, which is what you should do when asking questions here. As you can see, re-typing the code can introduce new problems, which can both slow down your getting an answer to the question (because time is spent pointing out the typo error, which you then say *that isn't my real code*) as well as wasting our time replying *You have a problem with your code here...*, to which you respond *that was a typo when I copied the code over*. A lot of wasted time and effort that wouldn't exist if you copy and paste your actual code instead.