# VBA Word: Deleting InlineShapes seems to change the end of For Loop

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have encountered a strange behaviour in VBA. I have written a code that deletes InlineShapes of certain size (and write them into a txt File). The code results in an error because the end of my for loop seems to change during running. Can someone help?

```
Function findAndRemovePics()

Dim i As Integer
Dim count As Integer
Dim str As String

currpath = "..."

'Set Objects
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(currpath & "linkliste_http.xlsx")  'Replace String with path to Excel File
Set xlWS = xlWB.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Replace String with your Worksheet Name

myFile = currpath & "imagelist.txt"

Open myFile For Output As #1

With ActiveDocument

  inlinenr = .InlineShapes.count
  'loop through inline shapes
  For i = 1 To inlinenr
    sngWdth = .InlineShapes(i).Width
    SngHght = .InlineShapes(i).Height
    If (sngWdth = SngHght And SngHght < 80 And sngWdth < 80 And sngWdth > 20 And SngHght > 20) Then
        ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(i).Select
        ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(i).Delete

        str = count & " " & sngWdth & " " & SngHght & vbNewLine
        Print #1, str
        count = count + 1
    End If
  Next i

End With
Close #1

End Function
```

Comment: This is a common issue with deleting items from a collection. When you delete the object, you've changed the count. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23511563/remove-currently-looped-item-from-collection

Comment: Indeed, it is a shame that VBA does not offer a reverse for each because when you are deleting from a collection you should start at count and work toward 1 using Step -1.  In this way you won't try to access items that you have already deleted.