# Fastest way of Parsing Json to Excel using VBA

Tags: json, excel, vba

I have been parsing data from JSON to Excel and the code is working fine but it takes much time to write data which is more than 1 minute.

Every Column has 5K rows of data. I have searched to find better way of parsing data into excel with less time but no success.

I do hope there will be an way of achieving this. Any help will be much appreciated

```
Sub parsejson()

Dim t As Single
t = Timer
Dim objRequest      As Object
    Dim strUrl      As String
    Dim blnAsync    As Boolean
    Dim strResponse As String
    Dim idno, r     As Long
    Dim ws, ws2    As Worksheet
    Dim JSON        As Object
    Dim lrow As Long
    
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    
    Set ws = Sheet1
    Set ws2 = Sheet2
    
    Set objRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    strUrl = ""
    blnAsync = True
    
    With objRequest
        .Open "GET", strUrl, blnAsync
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
        .send
        
        While objRequest.readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Wend
      
    strResponse = .ResponseText
    End With
    
    Dim resultDict As Object
    Set resultDict = ParseJson("{""result"":" & strResponse & "}")
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim resultNum As Long
    resultNum = resultDict("result").Count
    r = 2
    For i = 1 To resultNum
 
        ws.Cells(r, "B").Value = resultDict("result")(i)("productName")
        ws.Cells(r, "C").Value = resultDict("result")(i)("upc")
        ws.Cells(r, "D").Value = resultDict("result")(i)("asin")
        ws.Cells(r, "E").Value = resultDict("result")(i)("epid")
        ws.Cells(r, "G").Value = resultDict("result")(i)("platform")
        ws.Cells(r, "I").Value = resultDict("result")(i)("uniqueID")
        ws.Cells(r, "L").Value = resultDict("result")(i)("productShortName")
        ws.Cells(r, "M").Value = resultDict("result")(i)("coverPicture")
        ws.Cells(r, "N").Value = resultDict("result")(i)("realeaseYear")
        ws.Cells(r, "Q").Value = resultDict("result")(i)("verified")
        ws.Cells(r, "S").Value = resultDict("result")(i)("category")
        ws2.Cells(r, "E").Value = resultDict("result")(i)("brand")
        ws2.Cells(r, "F").Value = resultDict("result")(i)("compatibleProduct")
        ws2.Cells(r, "G").Value = resultDict("result")(i)("type")
        ws2.Cells(r, "H").Value = resultDict("result")(i)("connectivity")
        ws2.Cells(r, "I").Value = resultDict("result")(i)("compatibleModel")
        ws2.Cells(r, "J").Value = resultDict("result")(i)("color")
        ws2.Cells(r, "K").Value = resultDict("result")(i)("material")
        ws2.Cells(r, "L").Value = resultDict("result")(i)("cableLength")
        ws2.Cells(r, "M").Value = resultDict("result")(i)("mpn")
        ws2.Cells(r, "O").Value = resultDict("result")(i)("features")
        ws2.Cells(r, "Q").Value = resultDict("result")(i)("wirelessRange")
        ws2.Cells(r, "T").Value = resultDict("result")(i)("bundleDescription")

        r = r + 1
    Next i
    
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    
    MsgBox "RunTime : " & Format((Timer - t) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you time and pinpoint where the bottleneck is? Is it the request, parsing or writing to worksheet? Also this looks more suitable for CodeReview.

Comment: It is taking the time while writing the data on sheet. Whereas response comes in immediate window within 0.00 seconds.

Comment: This code works, so is better posted on the CodeReview Stack.

Comment: So, the problem is not parsing the JSON response as implied by the title, but writing to the sheet...?

Comment: Yes you are right.

Comment: You can make an array and populate it with the data then write once into the sheet for **each** continuous range. What you are doing now is writing 23 times per row, multiply that with 5k rows of data = 115k times!

Comment: Yes you are right but the Arrays are most difficult thing in this world.

Comment: I think you already have the array, you have returned from your converter.  `resultDict("result")(i).Items()`

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I'm not sure how useful is that array though as he is writing into multiple continuous range (and 2 different worksheets)

Comment: @RaymondWu  Apologies, i didnt notice that.

Comment: @Arham There are plenty of resources on the topic of Array, you have to read and practice them if you want to improve.

Comment: I will definitely try from now on.

Comment: which json parser are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing/Reading value to/from cell is a very slow operation, even more so when you are doing that so many times in a row therefore populating your data in an array and write into the cells in blocks is the best way.

Since your requirement involves multiple continuous range, you will have to write into the sheet multiple times.

Replace your entire `For` loop with the below code, not the prettiest but should work:

```
Dim dataArr() As Variant
    ReDim dataArr(1 To resultNum, 1 To 4) As Variant
    For i = 1 To resultNum
        dataArr(i, 1) = resultDict("result")(i)("productName")
        dataArr(i, 2) = resultDict("result")(i)("upc")
        dataArr(i, 3) = resultDict("result")(i)("asin")
        dataArr(i, 4) = resultDict("result")(i)("epid")
    Next i
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, "B"), ws.Cells(1 + resultNum, "E")).Value = dataArr
                
    ReDim dataArr(1 To resultNum, 1 To 1) As Variant
    For i = 1 To resultNum
        dataArr(i, 1) = resultDict("result")(i)("platform")
    Next i
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, "G"), ws.Cells(1 + resultNum, "G")).Value = dataArr
    
    ReDim dataArr(1 To resultNum, 1 To 1) As Variant
    For i = 1 To resultNum
        dataArr(i, 1) = resultDict("result")(i)("uniqueID")
    Next i
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, "I"), ws.Cells(1 + resultNum, "I")).Value = dataArr
    
    ReDim dataArr(1 To resultNum, 1 To 3) As Variant
    For i = 1 To resultNum
        dataArr(i, 1) = resultDict("result")(i)("productShortName")
        dataArr(i, 2) = resultDict("result")(i)("coverPicture")
        dataArr(i, 3) = resultDict("result")(i)("realeaseYear")
    Next i
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, "L"), ws.Cells(1 + resultNum, "N")).Value = dataArr
    
    ReDim dataArr(1 To resultNum, 1 To 1) As Variant
    For i = 1 To resultNum
        dataArr(i, 1) = resultDict("result")(i)("verified")
    Next i
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, "Q"), ws.Cells(1 + resultNum, "Q")).Value = dataArr
    
    ReDim dataArr(1 To resultNum, 1 To 1) As Variant
    For i = 1 To resultNum
        dataArr(i, 1) = resultDict("result")(i)("category")
    Next i
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, "S"), ws.Cells(1 + resultNum, "S")).Value = dataArr
    
    ReDim dataArr(1 To resultNum, 1 To 9) As Variant
    For i = 1 To resultNum
        dataArr(i, 1) = resultDict("result")(i)("brand")
        dataArr(i, 2) = resultDict("result")(i)("compatibleProduct")
        dataArr(i, 3) = resultDict("result")(i)("type")
        dataArr(i, 4) = resultDict("result")(i)("connectivity")
        dataArr(i, 5) = resultDict("result")(i)("compatibleModel")
        dataArr(i, 6) = resultDict("result")(i)("color")
        dataArr(i, 7) = resultDict("result")(i)("material")
        dataArr(i, 8) = resultDict("result")(i)("cableLength")
        dataArr(i, 9) = resultDict("result")(i)("mpn")
    Next i
    ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(2, "E"), ws2.Cells(1 + resultNum, "M")).Value = dataArr
    
    ReDim dataArr(1 To resultNum, 1 To 2) As Variant
    For i = 1 To resultNum
        dataArr(i, 1) = resultDict("result")(i)("features")
        dataArr(i, 2) = resultDict("result")(i)("wirelessRange")
    Next i
    ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(2, "O"), ws2.Cells(1 + resultNum, "Q")).Value = dataArr
    
    ReDim dataArr(1 To resultNum, 1 To 1) As Variant
    For i = 1 To resultNum
        dataArr(i, 1) = resultDict("result")(i)("bundleDescription")
    Next i
    ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(2, "T"), ws2.Cells(1 + resultNum, "T")).Value = dataArr
```

Comment: Sorry for being late reply. This seems to be very great thank you very much @Raymond Wu can you please share that how to know the Column reference >

Comment: I got it Thank you once again @Raymond Wu

Comment: There is one problem whenever i open the file and runs the code it takes approx. 40 to 55 seconds to paste the data  but when i again run it process data within 10 seconds. Same issue is with other solution. This is causing because of API late Response.

Comment: @Arham Nothing much we can do about that since it's dependent on the API server that is not in our control.

Comment: I have been trying to add one condition that is IF `"category":"Games"` if the JSON `category = Games` if <> then return empty then copy paste the data. @Raymond Wu I know this is basic thing but i am unable to create. Please help if you can.

Comment: @Arham Your question is totally unclear but I suppose the syntax you are looking for is `If resultDict("result")(i)("category") = "Games" Then`, you will have to throw this through all the `For` loop OR before writing to the sheet, do a loop through the entire thing and remove it from the collection might be better.

Comment: @Arham [Example on how to remove item from collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23511563/remove-currently-looped-item-from-collection)

Comment: I tried with https://imgur.com/undefined but having an error `Object required run time error 424`. Reviewing the link but could not understand.

Comment: @Arham link is broken. Post a new question if you want since it is out of scope of this question

Comment: [Question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68761738/adding-two-condition-into-the-array-but-having-an-error) please look at it.

Answer (score 2):

As already discussed, your code is not slow because of parsing the JSON, but because you write every value cell by cell. The interface between VBA and Excel is slow compared to things done in memory, so the way to go is to write the data into a 2-dimensional array that can be written all at once into Excel.

As the destination in Excel is not a single Range, I suggest to have a small routine that collects and writes data for one column. Easy to understand and easy to adapt if columns or field names changes.

```
Sub writeColumn(destRange As Range, resultDict As Object, colName As String)    
    Dim resultNum As Long, i As Long
    resultNum = resultDict("result").Count
    ' Build a 2-dimesional array. 2nd index is always 1 as we write only one column.
    ReDim columnData(1 To resultNum, 1 To 1) As Variant
    For i = 1 To resultNum
        columnData(i, 1) = resultDict("result")(i)(colName)
    Next
    ' Write the data into the column
    destRange.Cells(1, 1).Resize(resultNum, 1) = columnData
End Sub
```

For every field/column, you need a call in your main routine (but without any loop)

```
Call writeColumn(ws.Cells(r, "B"), resultDict, "productName")
(...)
Call writeColumn(ws2.Cells(r, "E"), resultDict, "brand")
(...)
```

Comment: Sorry for being late reply. Thank you very much its working great @FunThomas

Comment: There is one problem whenever i open the file and runs the code it takes approx. 40 to 55 seconds to paste the data  but when i again run it process data within 10 seconds. Same issue is with other solution. This is causing because of API late Response.